# SQL/Laravel query needed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image]

Let's say that there is **relationships** table which contains pairs of users and their properties.

What should SQL query look like if I want to get all of the properties owned by particular UserID?

**Provide UserID->Get all the rows with columns from PROPERTIES table**

If that is also possible to query using Laravel Query Builder please let me know how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to get the user with properties in this case, it would be:

```
User::with('properties');
```

If! in you defined your relationship in User.php

```
function properties(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Property', 'PropertyID','CustomerId'); //you are not using Laravel conventions, you need the last two parameters.
}
```

Edit: I actually do not know how to do many to many relationships in query builder, but if you can do it with Eloquent I rather that.